# What takes precedent: Route value or form POST with the same name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, post

Suppose I have a route that looks like `/controller/action/UserID` that Accepts POSTs.

Then suppose someone POSTs to that url, with a variable called UserID set to something else.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is ever the possibility of a security issue with one value "sneaking" past the permission checks I do.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the parameter source's precedence is determined by the `ValueProviderFactories.Factories` collection where (by default) the POST-ed parameters takes precedence over the route data during the model binding.

So if someone POST UserId = 666 to your `/controller/action/777` url in your controller `UserId` will be 666.

This article's [Value Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) section gives a nice overview how this works:

> At run time, ASP.NET MVC uses the value providers registered in the
>   ValueProviderFactories class to evaluate request values that the model
>   binders can use.
>
> By default, the value provider collection evaluates values from the
>   various sources in the following order:
>
> 1. Previously bound action parameters, when the action is a child
>      action
> 2. Form fields (`Request.Form`)
> 3. The property values in the JSON
>      Request body (`Request.InputStream`), but only when the request is an
>      AJAX request
> 4. Route data (`RouteData.Values`)
> 5. Querystring parameters
>      (`Request.QueryString`)
> 6. Posted files (`Request.Files`)

Comment: Does that mean a sloppy programmer can access the Model (that has a UserID) and the method `Action(string UserID, MyObjectWithUserID o)` where `UserID != o.UserID` or does that mean `UserID` always equals `o.UserID`

Comment: All the parameters us the same binding process so the same paramaters get same values so `UserID` always equals `o.UserID`.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of parameter precedence, you should be checking that the user has permission to access the specified `UserID` on all POSTs as well as your GETs.

A user can just as easily sneak in an extra `UserID` parameter as change the form `action` to a URL with a different `UserID` in the path as these are just client side variables.

`<form method="post" action="/controller/action/1">`

could easily be changed to

`<form method="post" action="/controller/action/2">` on the client.

This would be just as easy as adding a hidden field: `<form method="post" action="/controller/action/1"> <input type="hidden" name="UserID" value="2" />`

If your controller method signature is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(model model, int userId)
```

And you are only using the `userId` in the input parameter (e.g. not accessing `Request.Form` directly or a value from the `model`) then it does not matter what the parameter precedence is. You should validate that the current logged in user has permission to view or edit the ID of `userId` within your controller POST method since that all client-side provided parameters cannot be trusted anyway.

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(model model, int userId)
{
    if (CurrentUserHasPermissionToEdit(userId))
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
      // Reject
    }
}
```